# Is it possible to represent a class whose prototype is defined at runtime in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some JavaScript code that generates a class based on a data structure, with the names and signatures of its methods depending on the contents of that data structure. Is it possible to represent this relationship in TypeScript? Failing that, is it possible to at least indicate that the output class has some specific (but unknown at compile time) set of methods, with a specific set of possible method signatures?

In my particular case, the input data might look something like this:

```
{
  'methodName1': {
    'flag1': true,
    'flag2': false
  },
  'methodName2': {
    'flag1': false,
    'flag2': false
  }
}
```

and the resulting class with have methods `methodName1` and `methodName2`, with the signature of each method being one of 4 predefined method signatures based on the values of the flags.

Comment: Since Typescript really only exists during compile-time, it makes sense that it can't help you with typing information during run-time.

If the data structure is constant of course, you might be able to make a type based on it. If it's only accessible at runtime though, I'm not sure you can do any better than just typing your dynamic objects as just key-value pairs.

Do you have an example of the code you'll be writing?

Comment: Using an abstract interface instead of a specific class might work better for you

Comment: Do you want to generate these classes at runtime or at compiletime? Please clarify. Type safety is checked at compile time. Runtime comes after compiletime. Thus, you can't define an interface at runtime used at compiletime. Consider that this is a [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): maybe your problem does not require typesafety / compiletime checks (you think you have to generate classes while actually not necessary).

Comment: I said that it's at runtime in the title of the question. This is part of an existing API, and changing that API is not a viable option. And I understand that runtime comes after compile time. What I'm trying to understand is the extent to which this can be represented in TypeScript so that I can provide at least partial type safety. As I said in the question, I would like to know if I can at least indicate that the methods on the generated class have a specific set of method signatures, even though I can't specify the names.

Comment: I apologize, I did not re-read the title and found no trace of "when" in the question. How is defined what these methods do (where does their implementation come from)? Just defining empty methods can't be of any used. Are they assuming that some base class provides a "peer" interface or will they refer to nothing (take data via arguments and return results) or to globals? How does the rest of the application know how to call those methods? Please show a bit more example (pseudo) code. Are there undetermined method names in the JSON or will the JSON pass a small subset of known methods?

Comment: The names are pretty much arbitrary valid identifiers. I don't see how the rest is relevant. I'm asking about type definitions for specific method signatures; I don't understand why the implementations of those methods would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

With your flag examples, you might be able to create a factory of sort using intersection types:

```
type Switch<A, B, C, D> =
  & ((f1: false, f2: false) => A)
  & ((f1: false, f2: true) => B)
  & ((f1: true, f2: false) => C)
  & ((f1: true, f2: true) => D);

declare let provider: Switch<
  (arg: number) => number,
  (arg: string) => string,
  (arg: boolean) => boolean,
  (arg: Date) => Date
>;

let afun = provider(false, false);
afun(3); // returns number

let bfun = provider(false, true);
bfun("hello"); // returns string

let cfun = provider(true, false);
cfun(false); // returns boolean

let dfun = provider(true, true);
dfun(new Date()); // returns Date
```